# TableView offset

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

By implementing a tableView within a pageViewController, the tableView is not in line with the content it is displaying. What is the best fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your `UIPageViewController` is not wrap within a `UINavigationController`

Answer (score 0):

If your table view is the first view in the view controller's view, the view controller will set its `contentInset` value to move things below the navigation bar. There's a setting in IB for this:

[image: Adjust Insets]

But now that your table view isn't the first object on the view, it's no longer getting this automatic benefit. So you need to do it yourself with code. Probably something similar to this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
}
```

64 won't be the exact number for all apps. For example, your navigation bar might be thinner in landscape mode on the phone. So you may want to actually use the view controller's top layout guide value here.

Notice I added 20 at the bottom to leave room for your page indicator. This assumes the table view would display behind it. You could measure that object at runtime also.

You might also fix the problem just by making the table view the back-most view in the hierarchy.